# UITableView under UINavigationBar with a black top background in IOS 9

Tags: ios, core-data

I just push a `UITableViewController` under `UINavigationBar`, but during the animation before `UINavigationBar` appears, the top is black, and after the `UINavigationBar` appears, there is a black top behind it. As below:
[image]

Here is my setting for the `UITableViewController`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Has the same issue, but I fixed refer this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614526/1316907

Here is my solution:

- Change "Launch Image Source" to Brand Assets
- Change "Launch Screen File" to MainStoryBoard if you don't have Launch.screen.storyboard

Hope it help.

[image]