# iOS 9 Xcode 7 - Application appears with black bars on top and bottom

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

Installed the app on iPhone 6 iOS9 and here is what happened. Notice black bars on top and bottom. It works just fine on iOS8. How I can fix it?

I've tried building with Xcode 6.4 & 7. Same result.

(iPhone 5 used to run iPhone 4 apps like this)

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem on iPhone 6 just after upgrading to iOS 9

Comment: Are you using navigation or tab bar controller in your app?

Comment: @RonWood Both actually.

Comment: Try the fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312906/ios9-app-has-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: Quick fix: Under Project/Targets/"App Icons and Launch Images", for App Icon source choose "AppIcon" (ie use ASSET CATALOG), then delete all `Default-568h@2x.png` style launch screen files. Clean, build, should be full screen on every device

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Did you migrate your app from an earlier version of Xcode? If so then Xcode is now making an assumption about your screen size and you need a way of indicating the actual screen size at run time.

There are two ways:

**a) If you use a launch screen.**

You are missing a LaunchScreen.storyboard file.
Create a Launch Screen object from the <kbd>New File...</kbd> dialog

[image: launch screen creation]

**b) If you don't use a launch screen.**

Go to your Target's settings and choose General, then App Icons and Launch Images.
Now set "Launch Screen File" to your "main.storyboard" (or another storyboard if appropriate)

Comment: What should be the contents of LaunchScreen.storyboard? I get an error saying OSX storyboards do not support target device "iphone"

Comment: You do not need a LaunchScreen file. Another option is to provide the needed launch images for each supported screen size.

Comment: i have same issue while open app in iOS 9.1, but my issue was resolve by adding the launch screen images for all the resolution, thanks to @rmaddy

Comment: In my case I need change "Launch Screen File" to MainStoryBoard if you don't have Launch.screen.storyboard to make it work

Comment: @Sausage Our application is working on zoom mode(no launch screen, no launch images, no constraints, just default-568h@2x). so how can we support iphone x?

Comment: This worked for me, but not exactly as above. I started my app in Xcode 13 beta, but need to move to Xcode 12 so I can submit it. What it did was unselect the device orientations and removed the Launch screen file. So although I had a launch screen it was not hooked up.

Answer (score 31):

My App does not use a launch image.
Setting the "Launch Screen File" to my "main.storyboard" file fixed the issue for me.

This setting can be found under "Target->General->App Icons and Launch Images"

Use the following link for more information:
http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

Comment: This worked for me and seems like a much better solution than adding a random new storyboard to your project.

Comment: If the project is Parse IOS swift starter project, Go to Target->General->App Icons and Launch Images and the "Launch Screen File" dropdown value is empty. So choosing the "Main.storyboard" will resolve the "black bars on top and bottom" issue.

Comment: This solution will not work if you need to provide custom view for launch image or your launch image is different from storyboard initial view controller.

Answer (score 17):

For me the problem is i'm migrating my app from earlier version of Xcode and the project is missing LaunchScreen.storyboard file. I have just created LaunchScreen.storyboard and added it to launch Screen File. This did the trick.
 [image: Application with black bars on top and bottom solution]

Answer (score 6):

I'm using xcode 7.2 . At first, I created a LaunchScreen.storyboard file, as [Potassium Permanganate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411070/potassium-permanganate)
suggested, and it worked! However, I didn't want a launch screen, so I tried setting Main.storyboard as Launch Screen File and it did the trick!

[image: xcode 7.2]

Answer (score 6):

This one is if you do not use storyboard at all.

It occurs when you remove `LaunchScreen` from `Launch Screen File` in `App icons and Launch Images`.
[image]

Instead of removing it from here go to info.plist and find `Launch screen interface file base name` and remove `LaunchScreen`, i.e. leave it blank.
[image]

It wont show in info.plist if you have removed `LaunchScreen` already from `Launch Screen File`. Then you can give any name in `Launch Screen File` and it will appear and you can remove the name.

Comment: Great supplemental answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you migrate your app from earlier version of xCode to xCode 6 or xCode 7, you will face this issue.

For iOS 7 and earlier, developers need to provide separate launch 
images for all screen sizes, resolutions and orientations their app supported.

In Xcode 6 or later, there is another option. You can specify a storyboard whose initial view controller will then be used as the app’s launch screen. Use below steps:

- Create a blank storyboard file named LaunchScreen.storyboard.
- Go to your target settings and, on the "General" tab, select the storyboard as your Launch Screen File in "App Icons and Launch Images" section. Xcode will add a corresponding UILaunchStoryboardName key to your app’s Info.plist. When this key is present, Xcode will prioritize it over any launch images you might have set.
- Add some subviews to newly created storyboard's view and position them with constraints. When you launch the app on a device, the OS should use the scene as the launch screen.

Delete the older app from simulator and clean the project.

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue in my app . In my app i have multiple targets added to project . If i use launch storyboard solution then i can see full screen but in my case my Lunch image looks blurred and stretched on iPhone 4 . To come out from this issue I have used LaunchImage asset solutions . After this still I am facing same issue .I have tried all above solutions, At end I found my png images don't include **ALPHA** resolutions . After adding new images ,i can see full screen images .

Answer (score 2):

iOS changed the way the system detects the resolution of the iPhone. You used to have to supply a number of png images named things like "Default-568@2x.png", "Default-667h@3x.png". Now you don't have to do that anymore. You need to delete those "Default-568@2x.png" style files and move on to using a proper LAUNCH SCREEN object in your project.

To add a launch screen just go to the <kbd>New File...</kbd> dialog (File / New / File, or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

[image: launch screen creation]

Double click that new Launch Screen file to edit it. Be sure it is ticked "use as launch screen" in its properties.

Finally be sure to select your LaunchScreen.storyboard file under project properties / Targets / "App Icons and Launch Images"

[image: select your launch screen]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the asset catalog and create a new iOS launch Image. then in **Target>General>App Icons and Launch Images>Launch Image Source** you will see automatically the new Launch Image created in the assets catalog.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have several targets in the project and each one has it's own launch screen images. The weird thing one of the targets looks fine but others have those black bars. The thing was in the name of Launch folder inside assets. Change name to LaunchImage solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2

select LaunchScreen.storyboard if its empty

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have one asset with launch images however it was displaying the top and bottom dark bar as well.

I've tried the launch storyboard solution and yes it works but I didn't want to add a new file so, this is what I did to fix the issue:

1. Copied my launch images to another folder
2. Removed the existing LaunchImage asset
3. Added a new LaunchImage asset
4. Added the images to the new LaunchImage

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to target settings in xcode in that section go to App icons and launch images section in that section select launch screen file you will find a drop down of values select CDVLaunchScreeen value against launch screen file value

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on an iPod. To fix this, I replaced

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad</key>
<string>LaunchScreenIpad</string>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone</key>
<string>LaunchScreenIphone</string>
```

with

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad</key>
<string>LaunchScreenIpad</string>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone</key>
<string>LaunchScreenIphone</string>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipod</key>
<string>LaunchScreenIphone</string>
```

in Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

I had an old app (iOS 7.4 - 8.2) and after upgrading it got the same issue (getting black empty bar at the top), I managed to solve it by:

> Main.storyboard
> Choose your Scene & Controller
> on left menu, go to Attribute Inspector
> find "Presentation" and instead of "Automatic" set it to "**Full Screen**"

[image]

It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

My app is written in python kivy. This is what I did. It worked.

1. The reason is that I don't have AppIcon and LaunchImage defined.
   There is free website that can provides you a set of icons and
   launchImages for various devices.
2. Once you have the full set, usually 2 folders - AppIcon and
   LaunchImage folder. Open your Xcode project, General > AppIcon and
   Launch images.
3. In the AppIcon Source, click the arrow on the right. It will go to
   another page, in which you can drag and drop the two folders in
   (yes, drag the folders).
4. Go back to the previous General tab, in the AppIcon Source, you can
   select your folder, usually called AppIcon-1. And tick 'include all
   icon asset'
5. Leave 'Launch Screen File' blank. This is very different from
   previous Xcode version.
6. Under the deployment info, status bar style, you can tick require
   full screen.

After those steps you should be good to load again.

Please note these steps are for a non storyboard app. In my case, my app is written in kivy.

Answer (score -1):

Don't Do anything that are described in earlier answers...

> To show view Controller follow the following single step
>
> `Step 1 : Add the splash Screen for iPhone and iPad.`

After this this error will not come again.