# Top and bottom cut off in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have an app that was just working fine until something happened and now every time I run it in the simulator, the top is lowered and the bottom is cut off. [Here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOfzk.png)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: You need a launch screen.