# View controller is not presenting in full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

enter link description herei don't why my view controller is not presenting in full screen.. i don't know what i am doing wrong.. Any one please give some suggestion to fix this issue.. i am running in on iPod 5th generation.. Even if i run in simulator also i am getting same issue..[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some additional information, such as the Storyboard view settings or how you are constructing the view and which device this is running on?

Comment: I have taken 1 view controller and setup all the text field and assign it as initial view controller..

Comment: What do you have for the width and height settings in the bar below the view? See this screenshot: http://cl.hb.tc/223M1c052G3l.

Comment: No i have not got like this

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: i am using Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 Xcode 7 - Application appears with black bars on top and bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom)

Comment: Done.. Thank you it is working ..

Comment: @Nithya Problem is not with your view. Actually your app is not supporting all devices and your simulator is not one of supported devices. Make sure you have included splash/launch screens for all devices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try programmatically setting:

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

In your ViewController main file.

Otherwise, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom), try creating a LaunchScreen.xib file if you are using a launch screen, or otherwise:

> Go to your Target's settings and choose General, then App Icons and Launch Images. Now set "Launch Screen File" to your "main.storyboard" (or another storyboard if appropriate)

Comment: Thank you Hersh but it is not working..

Comment: I have updated the answer to include additional options.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the

[image]

Tap this will solve issue

Answer (score 0):

You are set Launch Screen then check perfect your view because some time issue occur launch screen.