# Unable to solve issue in simulator device

Tags: ios, xib

My project UI work well for simulator 4s and also splash screen showing while running

but when I run on 5s or 6s device splash screen not showing and blank spaces appears header and footer of the view...

here is my 4s device simulator UI-
[image]

and this is 5s simulator UI-
[image]

Comment: Have you use auto layout and constraints?

Comment: did you check this answer?[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom]

Comment: just import the launch image in various resolution

Comment: Do you have the launch screen.xib added to your project and did u add the launch screen info to your plist ?

Comment: @iMash sir, yes i have use auto layout and constraints

Comment: @TejaNandamuri sir, my project have launchscreen.storyboard by default..and splash image successfully shown on simulator but when run app on real device blank screen comes instead of splash...this is my issue please sir give me some solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the different size of launch screen image or launch screen from interface builder.
[Please have a look this link](http://www.mobilemammoth.com/ios-app-icon-and-launch-image-sizes-for-iphone-6-and-6-plus/)
[image]