# iOS App is offset from the top of the Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I am developing an app (objective c) with a navigation controller. For some reason the whole app is offset from the top of the device. See below, can anyone give me some pointers as I have no idea.

Hiding the Navigation bar makes no difference, either in the storyboard or in code. The storyboard constraints all seem correct, as the title below the navigation bar moves up and down when showing and hiding the navigation bar.

[image]

This problem occurs on iPhone SE and iPhone 7, the iPad 2 is ok. The xCode version is 8.1
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which xcode you are using ? and In which device/Simulator version you have tested this ?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: did you added launch screen?

Comment: It's look like a problem with launch screen if it is it's a surprise that it exists even now with Xcode 8.1

Comment: No, I just added one and everything is working correctly.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 Xcode 7 - Application appears with black bars on top and bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `launch.storyboard` in your Project or you need to add `launch screens` image in your Asset Folder for all the sizes, then this black screen from top and bottom will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In App Icons and Launch Images setting, you need to set asset and launch screen file. so this black bar will disappear. [image]