# UINavigationController not full screen (swift)

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I create an empty project (in swift, xcode 8.3) and don't use storyboard, and a navigationcontroller into the window. I don't know why the navigationcontroller is not full screen

in AppDelegate, **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let nav = UINavigationController()
nav.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
nav.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.window?.rootViewController = nav
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The result is :

[image]

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 22):

The reason for the issue is that your project *has no launch screen*. Add a *LaunchScreen.storyboard* and configure your project to use it. It doesn't have to have any meaningful content; its mere presence is sufficient to prevent letterboxing which is what you're seeing.

[image]

[image]

Also, just as a secondary tip:

When you are going to insert a subview into a superview, you are always expressing the subview's `frame` in terms of the *superview's* coordinate system. It makes no sense to express it in terms of some other coordinate system as you are doing here.

So, replace

```
nav.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

with

```
nav.view.frame = self.window!.bounds
```

[image]

Comment: Should be accepted answer :)

Comment: I agree this should be accepted as the answer! Saved me a headache!