# stretch old iOS app on iPhone6 Plus screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a very old xcode/objective-c iOS project.
I tried to compile it on the lastest Xcode version and it works fine.
On big iPhones, the application is streched to fit in bigger screen.

I tried to create a new Xcode projet and drag all my source files in the new project. I removed storyboard.
It works, but the application is not stretched. I see 2 black bands at the top and the bottom of the screen.

What i want is just to understand which parameter i have to changed in the project.
This is not a storyboard or size classes issue because i have no storyboard or xib files. I tried to change iOS version déployment target.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a launch image for the large screen size of the plus models or better a launch screen file.
See: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754942/how-to-enable-native-resolution-for-apps-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

Answer (score 1):

Add launch images of of accurate sizes as follows for iOS 8 and later.

Goto launchScreen in the XCAssets, you can see these options on the right pane see the image attached.

and add images with size :- 
Image type             Size
Retina HD 5.5″         1242 × 2208 pixels
Retina HD 4.7″         750 × 1334 pixels

Comment: It does not work and I had not those files in my initial Xcode project...