# Application with black space on top and bottom after upgrade from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, macos-sierra

I updated my MacOS from El Capitan to Sierra, previously I'm using xcode 6.4. when I update OS xcode version doesn't support to open in new OS. So, I have installed xcode 8.3 version run the application in simulator with black space on top and bottom.

I have changed view controller size from inferred to free form and trying to update frames using editor->Resolve auto layout issues. but the option is in disable state.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: To resolve the black letterbox issue you need to create a LauncScreen.xib file, google for it, there are plenty of documentation on the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 Xcode 7 - Application appears with black bars on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Please delete previous launch screen and add again launch screen. Hope you will find the solution.