# black background to image used in LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to set an image in my Splash Screen inside LaunchScreen.xib and the image there looks fine but then when I launch my app the image shows with black background.

Note: there is no black background on preview inside LaunchScreen.xib. And when Im using the same image in other place in the app it works greate and there in no background but only the logo

Comment: black background at top and bottom ??

Comment: yes clack background all around the logo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: no its black background around the logo , not around the page. The page is ok but when I set an image the image shows with background.

Answer (score 0):

Your launch images source might set to use asset catalogs, go to your **Target -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images** and see if it's set correctly.

[image]