# Screens of an iPhone App have a fixed aspect ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am adapting an iPad app (originally built on Objective C/Swift) for the iPhone.

I have removed all things from the UI, the only things left are:

- Blue fill - the navigation bar
- Red fill - the toolbar

The app appears to have the screen's aspect ratio somehow hard coded for the iPad. I am unable to make the app occupy the full screen using both the interface builder and directly editing the code of the `UIViewController`.

Doesn't work on iPhone X 11.4 and iPhone 5 9.3, works only on the iPad family.

The issue seems to be outside of the `UIViewController` or even the `UINavigationController`.

What project setting may be causing this issue?

- iPhone is allowed in Xcode, **Targeted Device Family** is **resolved** as `1, 2` for the whole project
- Requires full screen is checked for iPhone

The app on various iPhones:

[image: The app on various iPhones]

Interface builder - all seems fine there:

[image: Interface builder]

Comment: The problem looks like the app window size. Is it set in code in some skanky way?  Have you got a LaunchScreen?

Comment: I believe this is related to using launch images. Switching to using the launch screen should fix this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32641240/278629

Comment: Yes, the cause was that the launch screen (image) was only for iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check for launch images. You need to provide the all sizes of the launch image which are not provided.
You can also add missing sizes from the utilities bar.