# UIViews in iOS App being clipped with Simulator

Tags: ios

I just have no idea what is going on. I have been making some code changes to my app. Editing different UIViewControllers. I noticed, at some point, that there is now a top and bottom "clipping", for lack of a better description, in the Simulator. This does not occur on my iPad device.

This happens for all my UIViewControllers, even creating a new UIViewController from scratch and checking "Is Initial View Controller"

[image]

If I revert my code changes then the "clipping" is resolved. My problem is, that none of the code files I have change seem like they would have an effect on only the Simulator and cause this "clipping" issue.

Even as I revert my latest changes individually, remove Pods, clean the build folder each time, the Simulator always has this "clipping" issue.

None of the files I that have deltas should even be causing this "clipping" issue in the Simulator anyways.

I have Erased and Content and Settings and closed the Simulator Process as well and still no luck.

I feel like I missing something subtle and easy here and hoping someone will noticed.

[image]

Comment: This may help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: Are you using launch images or launch storyboard? This can be caused by using launch images and missing a few for key resolutions.

Comment: I am using Storyboard...

Comment: Thank you @Shubham that worked!