# UI not filling up entire screen. Black bars on top and bottom

Tags: ios, swiftui

My SwiftUI interface doesn't fill up the entire screen.

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: What it's supposed to look like]

This is what it actually looks like on the device:

[image: What it actually looks like]

This is my content view:

## ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(content: {
            Circle().fill(ColorManager.petSupportBlue).frame(width: 350, height: 350).position(x: -50, y:30).ignoresSafeArea()
            Circle().fill(ColorManager.petSupportBlue).frame(width: 350, height: 350).position(x: 50, y: -50).ignoresSafeArea()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: may be it will help you : [iOS 9 Xcode 7 - Application appears with black bars on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik didn't work for me

Comment: It's launch screen is not added issues. Please attach your demo project on git. also your testing with iOS 13

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting it the wrong way. Yes adding the launch screen fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(content: {
        Circle().fill(ColorManager.petSupportBlue).frame(width: 350, height: 350).position(x: -50, y:30).ignoresSafeArea()
        Circle().fill(ColorManager.petSupportBlue).frame(width: 350, height: 350).position(x: 50, y: -50).ignoresSafeArea()
    })
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

Comment: It shows the same way with the black bars on top and bottom

Comment: @DayemSaeed, tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4 - works fine. Which env do you use? Is this the same code as you tested?

Comment: Yes it is. My issue was solved by adding a launch screen. Thank you!