# Why my view in storyboard which subclasses SKView (to be used for Spritekit) doesn't accept any autolayout constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, autolayout

I have a UIView in storyboard called _gameView and I've applied constraints on it in storyboard. it subclasses SKView so I can present my scene in it but the problem is that it never gets the contrains from autolayout in storyboard at runtime, why?

Answer (score 1):

Sprite Kit scenes are presented by a special kind of UIView, [SKView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/), and do not use Auto Layout. Only UIKit does - Auto Layout handles the arrangement of UIViews.

Comment: So i should only use setframe: or setbounds to show them in my prefered place on the screen?  Assuming i have an i-ad banner which i want it to be shown on the top of my skview.

Comment: @Reza.ab yes. Go ahead . There will be no issues.

Comment: So i did this, Doesnt work! it still gets shown in a view with full width but centered and cropped (not full screen)                                           `SKView *skView1 = [[SKView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 100, 120)];                                                                                            SKScene * scene = [IntroScene sceneWithSize:skView1.bounds.size];                                      scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
`
Seems like i cant set a custom frame for my SKView and show it in  a prefered place on the screen,What am i doing wrong?

Comment: However i have tried doing this but the casted frame (someOtherView) also needs to be a skview which i cant define a frame for it using setFrame. `SKView * skView = (SKView*)someOtherView;`

Answer (score 0):

Basically setting the Main.storyboard as lunchscreen in the project's target did the trick,Found the correct answer, it's a bug in ios9 with spritekit and can be solved this way [iOS9 App has black bars on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312906/ios9-app-has-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom)