# iOS 10 Xcode 7.3.1 - iPhone5S - Black bars on top and bottom

Tags: ios, xcode7.3, uilaunchimagefile

I have given LaunchImage with the required images. And given the `Launch Image Source` as `LaunchImage`

Now, everything is working fine only issue is in iPhone5S - iOS10, i built the application in XCode7.3.1

Someone please help me.[Attached is the screenshot of my ImageAssets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG3rS.png)

Comment: Why use launch images? It's so much easier to use a single Launch screen file.

Comment: How could i define different resolution images there?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the similar issue and I got it fixed by adding the image with dimensions 640x1136 pixels in resources folder.

I have referred inputs from the below tags:
**[iOS9 App has black bars on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312906/ios9-app-has-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom)**

Hope, this will help!